# Is there a way for mouse to completely ignore an html element?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [css rule to disable text selection highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

On my homepage i have a script, which shows a clock at the top of my homepage. I dont like the fact that i can choose this clock with my mouse, see the picture.

[image]

So i want to know if there is a way to completely prevent an html element from being selected by the mouse.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CSS can do that.

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: the simplicity and power of CSS XD

Comment: One more thing... why there are 5 lines :S ???

Comment: One for each browser engine (Chrome,Safari = webkit, Chrome 1.0 = khtml, Firefox = moz, Opera = o) and one for those who implement the CSS3 spec correctly.

Comment: @Tom -So the last one is obsolete ? :)